# properly handle error message in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have a try/catch around a line of code but when it errors out It's not properly printing out the error. Currently:

```
try
{
    // code here
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    return Redirect::back()
              ->withErrors($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents()["message"]);
}
```

prints:

> {

Now if I use:

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
```

then I get:

> { "message":user doesn't exist }

How can I change this to, upon error, only print "user doesn't exist"?

Comment: What is `var_dump($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());` giving you?

Comment: ```"""
{\n
    "message": "User doesn't exist."\n
}\n
"""```

Comment: That's a json string. To get the message, you need to decode the string using `json_decode()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decode the json string so you can access the message attribute.

```
try {
    //code here
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $response = json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
    $message = $response->message;

    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a serialized JSON string with array access. This will obviously fail. Here a 1:1 solution which includes the JSON decoding.

```
try
{
    // code here
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    return (json_decode(Redirect::back()
              ->withErrors($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents()))->message;
}
```